# Blender Can't Open .fbx from mudbox

Tags: import

When I try to import an fbx, I get:

`Error Couldn't open file'C:\\Desktrop\\shottymud.fbx'`

I have uninstalled and reinstalled blender and mudbox both with no change.

Comment: 1. I assume you have checked to make sure the FBX Import/Export add-on is active.

2. Check the FBX version and type coming out of Mudbox. According to the add-on documentation, it supports 7.x bin. See:  https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX

Comment: Add-on is active.

Version:  7.5.0
Format:  Binary
Custom Writer: No
Axis Direction: Y-up
Units: Centimeters
Frame rate: 30.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Content:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Take:
 No take found


Still get error :(

Comment: Still looking for answers on this one.

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: Still need to solve this by tuesday.